# How to get a specific tr element without class or id from a html document with BeafutifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tr

I have got this webpage https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1451-apofasi-730-2021.html

and I need to scrape the second last row from the large table.
In other words, I need to get this (Ένδικα Μέσα -) from the table.

This is my progress so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import csv


URL = 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1451-apofasi-730-2021.html'
headers1 = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae", 
    "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")
soup3 = soup2.find('td', text = "Ένδικα Μέσα")
print(soup3)
```

Thank you very much

Thank you very much, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You near to a solution - Clean up you soups and try to get the parent of your result, this will give you the whole tr:

```
soup.find('td', text = "Ένδικα Μέσα").parent.get_text(strip=True)
```

or `find_next('td)` to access the text of its neighbour:

```
soup.find('td', text = "Ένδικα Μέσα").find_next('td').text
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

URL = 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1451-apofasi-730-2021.html'
headers1 = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae", 
    "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
row = soup.find('td', text = "Ένδικα Μέσα").parent.get_text(strip=True)
print(row)
```

#### Output

```
Eνδικα Μέσα -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector for that field. There's a easy way to copy the selector for a element using the inspector of your browser and clicking the html tag that you want in copy > Copy Selector.

With beautiful soup you can use the `soup.select(selector)`. [The documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) describes this better.